# Which is better to dispose the object?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, dapper, using

In case of this method:

```
public void Delete(int id)
{
    using (var connection = GetOpenConnection())
    {
        connection.Execute($"DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE Id = {id}");
    }
}
```

Or just:

```
GetOpenConnection().Execute($"DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE Id = {id}");
```

I wonder if the second is the best option to ease the maintenance and simplify.

Comment: The first because the second doesn't even close the connection and the first will handle closing on exceptions as well.

Comment: Why you even think that the second could be better? You are comparing disposing with not disposing. Of course the latter will fail sooner or later.

Comment: The question - as already mentioned - doesn't make sense as it stands. You're not disposing in the second example.

Comment: Just for fun, run this two pieces of code one thousand times trying to delete a row from a non-existing table, catching and logging the exception, my guess is the second option will exhaust your db connection pool.

Comment: I agree with your comments, the class that contains this method is implementing the IDisposable pattern, but this method can be consumed many times exhausting  all connections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering this requires an understanding of how Sql Server (and other databases) use connections, and how ADO.Net uses connection pooling.

Database servers tend to only be able to handle a limited a number of active connections at a time. It has partly to do with the limited available [ephemeral ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) on a system, but other factors can come into play, as well. This is means it's important to make sure connections are either always closed promptly, or that we carefully limit connection use. If we want a database to scale to a large number of users, we have to do both.

.Net addresses this situation in two ways. First, the ADO.Net library you use for database access (`System.Data` and company) includes a feature called **Connection Pooling**. This feature pools and caches connections for you, to make it efficient to quickly open and close connections as needed. The feature means *you should not try to keep a shared connection object active for the life of an application or session.* Let the connection pool handle this, and create a brand new connection object for most trips to the database.

The other way it addresses the issue is with the **IDisposable** pattern. `IDisposable` provides an interface with direct support in the runtime via the `using` keyword, such that you can be sure unmanaged resources for an object — like that ephemeral port on the database server your connection was holding onto — are cleaned up promptly and in a deterministic way, *even if an exception is thrown*. This feature makes sure all those short-lived connections you create  because of the connection pooling feature really are as short-lived as they need to be.

In other words, **the using block in the first sample serves an important function**. It's a mistake to omit it. On a busy system it can even lead to a denial of service situation for your database.

You get a sense of this in the question title itself, which asks, "Which is better to dispose the object?" Only one of those two samples disposes the object at all.

Answer (score 8):

First option gives you predictability: connection object returned from `GetOpenConnection()` will be disposed as soon as `connection.Execute` finishes.

On the other hand, if you use second approach, you can hope that the connection would be closed at some time in the future, but you have absolutely no certainty of when, and even if, it is going to happen.

Therefore one should prefer the first approach.

**Note:** Consider parameterizing your query. Even though in your situation insertion of the `id` into the query is non-threatening because `id`'s type is `int`, it is a good idea to use parameters consistently throughout your code.

Comment: Yeah, something like Dapper or a parametrized query would be ideal.

Comment: It's possible to exploit `int` values to accomplish sql injection if you allow the code to run on computers you don't control. End users can create arbitrary custom negative sign values.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Wow, that's scary! Is there an article somewhere to learn more about this nasty trick?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I was not able to find an example of an injection with custom negative sign values, in this case the DELETE will not be executed because there are no negative identifiers (id), so besides hitting performance by being busy, don't see the harm.

Answer (score 2):

You could approach the design in this manner.

```
using(var context = new CustomerFactory().Create())
     return context.RetrieveAll();
```

Then inside your `CustomerContext` you would have the dispose logic, the database connection, and your query.  But you could create inherit a `DbConnectionManager` class, which will deal with the connection.  But the entire class will be disposed, which would also salvage the connection manager.

```
public interface ICustomerRepository : IDisposable
{
     IEnumerable<Customer> RetrieveAll();
}

public interface ICustomerFactory
{
     ICustomerRepository Create();
}

public class CustomerFactory : ICustomerFactory
{
     public ICustomerRepository Create() => new CustomerContext();
}

public class CustomerContext : ICustomerRepository
{
     public CustomerContext()
     {
          // Instantiate your connection manager here.
     }

     public IEnumerable<Customer> RetrieveAll() => dbConnection.Query<Customer>(...);
}
```

That would be if you want to stub out an expressive call, kind of representing your fluid syntax in option two, without the negative impact.